# Adhoc failed to install - handle_install: API failed

Tags: xcode4.3, provisioning, adhoc

I'm facing a problem with Adhoc provisioning profile, i can't install my deployed app using adhoc provisioning profile on my customer iPad, this happen after I upgrade the xcode from 4.2 to 4.3.3, the device log is:

```
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: 00281000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620394
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: 00281000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.BQH85j/foo_extracted/Payload/My app.app
Jul  3 09:08:38 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: 00281000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Jul  3 09:08:40 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: 00281000 handle_install: API failed
Jul  3 09:08:40 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: 00281000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
Jul  3 09:08:40 unknown installd[1300] <Error>: 00281000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

I've deleted all my provisioning profiles, clean it from the computer, restart the computer, then download them from the portal, the same issue. I've checked the provisioning profile by opening it using textEdit and checked the `get-task-allow` boolean, it's set to false.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happen when deploying the app using Development certificate, then Archiving it using Distribution certificate. I've checked them and everything going well now. Hope that help someone else facing this problem.

Thank you.